# Moving file with DriveApp is very slow to synchronize

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the following code to move a specific file to a different folder:

```
function move_file(file_id, target_folder_id){

    var source_file = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
    var source_folder = source_file.getParents().next();

    if (source_folder.getId() != target_folder_id) {
        DriveApp.getFolderById(target_folder_id).addFile(source_file);
        source_folder.removeFile(source_file);
    }
}
```

It works fine, with one issue so far. When I move a file then go to a different browser window and open Google Drive the file still shows in the original folder. This does eventually rectify itself, but is taking about 1 to 2 minutes. Why so slow?

Any advice would be very welcome as it is confusing users to not see the file moved for a few minutes after my script finished running.

Thanks

Comment: 1 or 2 minutes? How long does it take for the script to run? I see slowness too but never that long. Mostly like 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive (and many other distributed/web applications) works on an "eventual consistency" model. This means that changes made are not instantaneously visible everywhere, but they are guaranteed to eventually be consistent across the application.

This is different from a traditional file system which is strongly consistent. When you have a file on a physical drive and you move it to a new location, it will never show as being in the "old" location, even for a brief time.

The eventual consistency model is an important part of large-scale distributed infrastructure like that on which Google Drive runs.  Google has many data centres around the globe, and millions of servers and drives storing your Google Drive data, with redundant copies distributed across different systems. When you send the command to change a file's parent location, that change must be distributed across all those different systems, which takes time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency